# Line-height in actionscript stylesheets

Tags: actionscript-3, stylesheet, css

I'm having problems with figuring out the ability to use css stylesheets in actionscript.

I'm trying to verticaly center text inside a textfield. I tried to use line-height but it doesn't do a thing. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Here's my code:

```
var style:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
style.parseCSS("a{color:#" + color + "; fontSize:" + fontSize + "; font-family: " + font + "; line-height: " + stageheight + "; text-align: center;}");
```

this is the link where i test my flash video:

http://www.stevevo.sin.khk.be/2SFlashGenerator/flashTest.php

You'll notice that other property's like color, fontsize and font are adjustable so the stylesheet itself works fine only line-height doesnt work.

Comment: There are better ways to center the text vertically.  Do it with flash, not css.

Comment: @Sam: In fact, it would be far better if it could be done with css. Unfortunately, Adobe "forgot" to include vertical-align, padding-top and padding-bottom.  :(

Comment: FYI: line-height in actionscript is leading prop. of TextFormat class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for vertical padding, margins and alignment in Flash CSS, so you will have to center the TextField instead of the text:

1. set `textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;`  If you then specify `width` as well, the TextField will resize only in height.
2. set `textField.y = (textField.parent.height - textField.height) * .5;`

The latter will place the TextField at the vertical center of its parent DisplayObject.

Comment: btw lineHeight will apply only in between lines of text.